# BASH Iterating into an array from a file

Tags: bash

If I have document and want to iterate the second column of the document into an array, would there be a simple way to do this. At present I am trying by using:

`cat file.txt | awk -F'\t' '{print $2}' | sort -u`

This lists all the unique items in the second column to standard out.

The question is ...how do I now add these items to an array, considering some of these items have whitespace.

I have been trying to declare an array

`arr=()`

and then tried

`${arr}<<cat file.txt | awk -F'\t' '{print $2}' | sort -u`

Answer (score 2):

Bash4+ has mapfile aka readarray plus a Process Substituion.

```
mapfile -t array < <(awk -F'\t' '{print $2}' file.txt | sort -u)
```

If you don't  have bash4+

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  array+=("$line")
done < <(awk -F'\t' '{print $2}' file.txt | sort -u)
```

To see the structure in the array

```
declare -p array
```

- By default read strips leading and trailing white space so to work around that you need to use `IFS=` to preserve the default line structure.
- The `-t` option from mapfile `-t        Remove a trailing DELIM from each line read (default newline)`

Comment: This perfectly answers the question.
+1 for adding non BASh4+

Comment: Good to know, you can accept the answer if you think it solves whatever you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Bash 3 has `read -a` to read `IFS` delimited fields from a file stream to an array.
The `-d ''` switch tells `read`, the record delimiter is `null`, so it reads fields until it reaches the end of the file stream `EOF` or a null character.

```sh
declare -a my_array
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a my_array < <(cut -f2 < file.txt | sort -u)
```